# Zend captcha image and color

Tags: zend-framework

I'd like to know how to customize colors for captcha image with zend_captcha_image.

The one I could make it work is like this

```
$this->captcha = new Zend_Captcha_Image();
$this->captcha->setWordLen('4')
               ->setHeight('60')
               ->setFont("font.ttf");
```

it comes with black text and white background, what if I want to use different colors for font in captcha image.

Answer (score 2):

The colours appear to be hard-coded into the `_generateImage()` method of the `Zend_Captcha_Image` class, so can't easily be changed. You would need to extend this class and override that method to use your own colours. Specifically these two lines:

```
    $text_color = imagecolorallocate($img, 0, 0, 0);
    $bg_color   = imagecolorallocate($img, 255, 255, 255);
```

Comment: thanks, I am writing an extend class to overwrite $text_color, but it seems text_color I set up doesn't change the actual color, it works with some colors like gray, but when I want to try with blue like 0, 0, 255, it still gives me black, still debugging it.